# A lot of undefined control sequences and missing { } $ errors

Tags: errors, amsmath

I don't want to open up too many threads so I'm combining two errors together. Sorry in advance.

The full paragraph in question

```
\documentclass {book}
\include {amsmath}
\begin {document}

\section {error prone}
The charge density is substituted by a superposition of a reference or 
input density $ n'_{0} = n_{0} ( \vec{r}' ) $and a small change of
$ \delta n' \eq \delta n (\vec {r}') , \int d \vec_{r}' $ is expressed by $\int '$

\end {document}
```

These lines are having undefined control sequences

This other error is

```
    ! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>

?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>

?
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>

?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>

?
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
```

I have included {amsmath}

Comment: please always post a complete test document not a fragment. `\eq` is not defined by default, just use `=`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done.

Comment: no a test document is a complete document that peopel can run to produce the error.

Comment: `\vec{r}` would not generate an error but is that the output you want? Did you intende to make something a subscript with `\vec_{r}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Im not sure. The dvi output displays it just fine, but it does throw the error. Yes I am looking to vectorize r

Comment: after an error message it is usually best not to even look at the typeset output (TeX does not try to generate sensible output after an error, just tries to recover enough to check more of the document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You neither showed the full document nor the full error message.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
The charge density is substituted by a superposition of a reference or 
input density $ n'_{0} = n_{0} ( \vec{r}' ) $and a small change of
$ \delta n' \eq \delta n (\vec {r}') , \int d \vec_{r}' $ is expressed by $\int '$
\end{document}
```

Produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 $ \delta n' \eq
                    \delta n (\vec {r}') , \int d \vec_{r}' $ is expressed b...

?
```

Where the linebreak shows how far TeX had got, and that the undefined command is `\eq`.  that should be `=`.

The document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
The charge density is substituted by a superposition of a reference or 
input density $ n'_{0} = n_{0} ( \vec{r}' ) $and a small change of
$ \delta n' = \delta n (\vec {r}') , \int d \vec_{r}' $ is expressed by $\int '$
\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.6 ...ta n' = \delta n (\vec {r}') , \int d \vec_
                                                  {r}' $ is expressed by $\i...

?
```

where again the linebreak highlights where the error is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
The charge density is substituted by a superposition of a reference or 
input density $ n'_{0} = n_{0} ( \vec{r}' ) $and a small change of
$ \delta n' = \delta n (\vec {r}') , \int d \vec{r}' $ is expressed by $\int '$
\end{document}
```

runs without error.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering why the line breaks appear during the output.